# Neo4j query not returning correct result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 3 types of nodes 'Project', 'User', 'Company' and these are related as follows:

```
(u : User)-[r:HAVE_DONATED{amount}]->(p : Project)
(c : Company)-[r:HAVE_DONATED{amount}]->(p : Project)
```

Two users can be friend and it can be checked as

```
(u1 : User)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->()-[:FRIEND]-()<-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]-(u2 : User)
```

if the above condition holds then two users are friend.

Now I have to find all the projects in which my friends have made the donations along with donation and count of donors.

```
Match (p : Project), (u1 : User {id : {id}}) with p, u1  
Optional Match (p)<-[r:HAVE_DONATED]-(u2) with a, u1, u2, r 
where (u1)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->()-[:FRIEND]-()<-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]-(u2) 
with p, count(u2) as donors, sum(toInt(r.amount)) as donations  
return {id : p.id, donor : donors, donation : donations} as project
```

This query giving me correct projects but the problem is donors and donations are not correct. In donors and donations it only counting users contribution not of both(user and company). I want combined donation of user and company.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

To find all the Projects that a user's friends have donated to, and the total donations to those Projects, you can use this query:

```
MATCH (u1:User {id : {id}})-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->()-[:FRIEND]-()<-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]-(u2:User)-[:HAVE_DONATE‌D]->(p:Project)
MATCH (donor)-[r:HAVE_DONATED]->(p)
WITH p, COUNT(donor) as donors, SUM(TOINT(r.amount)) AS donations
RETURN {id: p.id, donors: donors, donations:donations} AS project;
```

The query returns nothing if the User with id `{id}` has no friends who contributed to any Projects.

Comment: Thanks for the query but there is a small  problem with this query , in donation it will not take into account the donations made by non friend members. It will result the correct project but not correct donation. 
MATCH (u1:User {id : {id}})-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->()-[:FRIEND]-()<-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]-(u2:User)-[r1:HAVE_DONATED]->(p:Project)
OPTIONAL MATCH (c)-[r2:HAVE_DONATED]->(p)
WITH p, COUNT(c) as donors,  SUM(TOINT(r2.amount)) AS donations
RETURN {id: p.id, donors: donors,donations:donations} AS project